# In Stata why is outreg overwriting other files?

Tags: stata

When I use the outreg command in stata to export to one file and then use it to export to another file, and then go back to add more stuff to the original file, the command is acting as though there is only one file.  As you can see in the code below, I have clearly distinguished the two files:

```
    (...regression...)
    outreg using fileA, landscape title(Farm Level by ///
    Stratum w/Management) starlevels(10 5 1) ///
    ctitles("Variables","Strat 1 Log Rev") replace
    (...do some other stuff, export new stuff to new file...)
    outreg using fileB,stats(b) landscape ///
    title("Normalized Ricardian Model w/Management Variables"\ ///
    "Farm Level by Stratum") noautosumm ///
    ctitles("Variables","Strat 1 Log Rev (%)") replace
    (...then another regression which I want to export to the original file...)
    outreg using fileA,landscape title(Farm Level by ///
    Stratum w/Management) starlevels(10 5 1) ///
    ctitles("Variables","Strat 1 Log Cost") merge replace
    (...But it simply merges everything together as though fileA and fileB were one)
```

Comment: If the solution below does not suit you, take a look at the `estout` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
...
outreg ...  , merge(tblnameA)
...
outreg ...  , merge(tblnameB)
```

It's covered in http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=sg97_4

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into `outreg2`. It's user-contributed and allows you to specify append and replace options as well.
To install type

```
findit outreg2
```